# SQL Duplicates Reduction, Divide by count of subquery results

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, divide

guys!

I've run into a problem here.

I'm working with some records that have many duplicates. Each record has three keys, a personID, CostCtr (Cost Center) and Worked Location. 
A set of these duplicate records may look like the following:

```
PersonID    Cost Ctr    DaysInLocation  DaysInMonth
1111        256         3               28
1111        256         0               28
1111        256         3               28
1111        243         15              15
1111        243         15              15
1111        243         0               15
```

I want to create a result that will add up all the 'daysInLocation' and divide it by the count of 'daysInLocation' that are not 0, and to add all the daysInMonth divided by the count of daysInMonth.

The Result would look something like this:

```
PersonID    CostCtr DaysInLocation  DaysInMonth
1111        256     3               28
1111        243     15              15
```

I'm also looking how to divide a sum(stuff)/count(subquery), where the sum(stuff) and Count(subquery) share the same personID, CostCtr and other Key.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select personid, costctr
       sum(daysinlocation) / sum(case when daysinlocation <> 0 then 1 else 0
                                 end) as DaysInLocation,
       sum(DaysInMonth) / count(DaysInMonth)
from table t
group by personid, costctr;
```

The `DaysInMonth` expression could also be `avg(DaysInMonth) as DaysInMonth`.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely in the direction i'm going with this. I don't know how I forgot about avg, I guess it was 1130 pm when I was working on this, hah.
How about counting the results in a subquery and dividing days in location by that?
sum(daysinlocation)/count(subquery) ?

Comment: @user3191081 . . . I suppose you could put a subquery in the `from` clause.  Subqueries are not allowed as arguments to aggregation functions (at least in most dialects of SQL).

Comment: Ah, that's probably why I was getting an error before.
Thanks.